# Alonzo purple node not syncing

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

My Alonzo Purple stopped earlier today at:

```
{
    "epoch": 1138,
    "hash": "6da227172643387f26e2b95e7f8d781938a6084bc745fb5026134fa901bd5ef8",
    "slot": 8190079,
    "block": 358864,
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "syncProgress": "99.42"
}
```

https://explorer.alonzo-purple.dev.cardano.org/en is also stuck at the same place it seems

How do I get further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alonzo network is dead, you should move your testing to the Cardano testnet.